# In Allure Reports how can i made links with name and link by python

Tags: python, allure

I want to create links with name and links for the item.

Example in reports I have link name - Task 55188 and this link redirects me to `'http://tfs.com/tfs/company/rnd/QA/_testManagement?planId=41890&suiteId=55188&_a=tests'`

But how I create this in python code?

Comment: Please specify details: which task management system do you use? which version of `python`, `allure` and test runner (maybe `py.test1) do you use?

Comment: @MaxV OS- Windows, Python - 3.6, allure - 2.3.5, pytest

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is about specific code problems after YOU tried something yourself. SO is not a code generator. Show us what you've tried first

Comment: You should look into using `allure-link-pattern=link:"https://url/{}" ` in your codebase. 
Search how to implement that in your test runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With Decorators

Some allure-python integrations allow setting a link pattern with a cmd line switch. For example:

allure-pytest:

```
--allure-link-pattern=http://tfs.com/tfs/company/rnd/QA/_testManagement?planId=41890&suiteId={}&_a=tests
```

allure-behave:

```
-D AllureFormatter.link_pattern=http://tfs.com/tfs/company/rnd/QA/_testManagement?planId=41890&suiteId={}&_a=tests
```

When you set a link pattern, you don't need to create your own `allure_wrapper.py` like in Viktoriia's answer and can use `@allure.link:55188` directly.

---

### With Dynamic

In addition to the decorator approach above, a [`Dynamic`](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/blob/c21726294367f807d560ee5484847e6f54c384d3/allure-python-commons/src/_allure.py#L85-L141) class is available to dynamically add links to the report at runtime. For example:

```py
import allure

def some_test_function():
    allure.dynamic.link('http://tfs.com/tfs/company/rnd/QA/_testManagement?planId=41890&suiteId=55188&_a=tests', name='55188')
```

Some integrations may not support dynamic linking and will do nothing when `allure.dynamic.link` is called. For example, I had to add support for allure-behave by [implementing the relevant allure hooks in a PR](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/pull/574).

We use dynamic linking to conditionally add Jira defect links for failing tests. When a test fails, we create a Jira defect with a tag specific to the test. The next time that test fails, it queries the Jira REST API to find all issues matching the tag and links them. This way we can add/remove test links from Jira and avoid fumbling around with decorators in the test code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create allure_wrapper.py file inside your project and use decorator with task number/task title for your tests.

For example:

In your project you have a list of tasks:

*constants.py*

```
TASKS = {
    '55188': 'Test task'
}
```

Import this list and use in allure_wrapper.py for tasks decorator

*allure_wrapper.py*

```
from constants import TASKS
from allure import link, issue, story

# Specify your link pattern
TFS_LINK_PATTERN = 'http://tfs.com/tfs/company/rnd/QA/_testManagement?planId=41890&suiteId={}&_a=tests'

def task_link(task_id):
return link(TFS_LINK_PATTERN.format(task_id), name=f'{item_type} {task_id}')

def task_links(links):
decos = []
for link in links:
    decos.append(task_link(link))
    decos.append(story(TASKS[link]))
return compose_decos(decos)

def compose_decos(decos):
    def composition(func):
        for deco in reversed(decos):
            func = deco(func)
        return func
    return composition
```

Use created decorator to attach link:

```
from allure_wrapper import task_links

@task_links(['55188'])
def test_task_link():
    # do smth
```

As result a clickable link will be available in your allure reporting

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround for this:

```
allure.attach('<head></head><body><a href="' + your_link + '">Link to ...</a></body>', 'Logs', allure.attachment_type.HTML)
```